# Force Closes due to missing Android String Resource using APKtool - but string is present

Tags: android, string

I hope you can help - I've hunted everywhere and getting quite desperate as my Android Market ratings are taking a huge hit due to this. Here goes - thanks in advance.

I used APKtool to decompile a theme for GOContacts. Edited all the necessary files and recompiled. After uploading to the market the theme appears to work on most devices, but is force closing with this error on other devices.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jbapps.contact.theme.steampunk/com.jbapps.contact.theme.steampunk.GOContactsInstallDialog}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f040019
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f040019
at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:221)
at android.content.Context.getText(Context.java:173)
at android.app.Dialog.setTitle(Dialog.java:475)
at com.jbapps.contact.theme.steampunk.GOContactsInstallDialog.onCreate(GOContactsInstallDialog.java:46)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
... 11 more
```

The string resource I.D. #0x7f040019 points to the string name

```
<string name="dialog_title">Download GO Contacts</string>
```

Which is present in all my res\values\strings files in all available languages as below in:

```
\res\values-ko\strings.xml

<string name="dialog_title">다운로드 GO 연락처</string>

\res\values-ru\strings.xml



  <string name="dialog_title">Скачать GO Контакты</string>

\res\values-zh-rCN\strings.xml

\res\values-zh-rHK\strings.xml

\res\values-zh-rTW\strings.xml

<string name="dialog_title">下载 GO联系人</string>
```

All the string resources are accounted for as far as I can see. The other file that mentions the string is GOContactsInstallDialog.smali which I've bolded below.

```
    .class public Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog;
.super Landroid/app/Activity;
.source "GOContactsInstallDialog.java"


# annotations
.annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/MemberClasses;
    value = {
        Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog$CustomAlertDialog;
    }
.end annotation


# instance fields
.field private mDialog:Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog$CustomAlertDialog;


# direct methods
.method public constructor <init>()V
    .locals 0

    .prologue
    .line 15
    invoke-direct {p0}, Landroid/app/Activity;-><init>()V

    return-void
.end method

.method private isExistSkin(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
    .locals 2
    .parameter "packageName"

    .prologue
    .line 78
    .line 79
    const/4 v1, 0x2

    .line 78
    :try_start_0
    invoke-virtual {p0, p1, v1}, Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog;->createPackageContext(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/content/Context;
    :try_end_0
    .catch Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager$NameNotFoundException; {:try_start_0 .. :try_end_0} :catch_0

    .line 83
    const/4 v1, 0x1

    :goto_0
    return v1

    .line 80
    :catch_0
    move-exception v0

    .line 81
    .local v0, e:Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager$NameNotFoundException;
    const/4 v1, 0x0

    goto :goto_0
.end method


# virtual methods
.method protected onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
    .locals 4
    .parameter "savedInstanceState"

    .prologue
    .line 34
    invoke-super {p0, p1}, Landroid/app/Activity;->onCreate(Landroid/os/Bundle;)V

    .line 37
    const/4 v0, 0x1

    invoke-virtual {p0, v0}, Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog;->requestWindowFeature(I)Z

    .line 38
    const/high16 v0, 0x7f03

    invoke-virtual {p0, v0}, Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog;->setContentView(I)V

    .line 40
    const-string v0, "com.jbapps.contactpro"

    invoke-direct {p0, v0}, Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog;->isExistSkin(Ljava/lang/String;)Z

    move-result v0

    if-eqz v0, :cond_0

    .line 41
    invoke-virtual {p0}, Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog;->finish()V

    .line 68
    :goto_0
    return-void

    .line 45
    :cond_0
    new-instance v0, Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog$CustomAlertDialog;

    invoke-direct {v0, p0, p0}, Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog$CustomAlertDialog;-><init>(Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog;Landroid/content/Context;)V

    iput-object v0, p0, Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog;->mDialog:Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog$CustomAlertDialog;

    .line 46
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog;->mDialog:Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog$CustomAlertDialog;

    const v1, 0x7f040019

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog$CustomAlertDialog;->setTitle(I)V

    .line 47
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog;->mDialog:Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog$CustomAlertDialog;

    invoke-virtual {p0}, Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog;->getResources()Landroid/content/res/Resources;

    move-result-object v1

    const v2, 0x7f04001a

    invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Landroid/content/res/Resources;->getString(I)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v1

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog$CustomAlertDialog;->setMessage(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V

    .line 48
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog;->mDialog:Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog$CustomAlertDialog;

    const/4 v1, -0x1

    invoke-virtual {p0}, Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog;->getResources()Landroid/content/res/Resources;

    move-result-object v2

    **const v3, 0x7f040018**

    invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Landroid/content/res/Resources;->getString(I)Ljava/lang/String;

    move-result-object v2

    new-instance v3, Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog$1;

    invoke-direct {v3, p0}, Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog$1;-><init>(Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog;)V

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1, v2, v3}, Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog$CustomAlertDialog;->setButton(ILjava/lang/CharSequence;Landroid/content/DialogInterface$OnClickListener;)V

    .line 67
    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog;->mDialog:Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog$CustomAlertDialog;

    invoke-virtual {v0}, Lcom/jbapps/contact/theme/steampunk/GOContactsInstallDialog$CustomAlertDialog;->show()V

    goto :goto_0
.end method

.method protected onDestroy()V
    .locals 1

    .prologue
    .line 72
    invoke-super {p0}, Landroid/app/Activity;->onDestroy()V

    .line 73
    invoke-static {}, Landroid/os/Process;->myPid()I

    move-result v0

    invoke-static {v0}, Landroid/os/Process;->killProcess(I)V

    .line 74
    return-void
.end method
```

I would love a solution to this as it's really ruining my day, if there is any other info I should add please let me know. Thank you all.

Comment: clean the project once. it will resolve.

Comment: Hi @Padma Kumar, Thank you very much for the fast response  -I'm not using Eclipse though. I'm decompiling and compiling using APKTOOL only. Should I import the project into eclipse and try that way? Would it understand .smali files? Apologies for any stupidity on my part - learning as I go. Thank you again Sir